# Improving the speed of Solr query over 16 million tweets

Tags: java, search, solr, information-retrieval, solrcloud

I use Solr (SolrCloud) to index and search my tweets. There are about 16 million tweets and the index size is approximately 3 GB. The tweets are indexed in real time as they come so that real time search is enabled. Currently I use `lowercase` field type for my tweet body field. For a single search term in the search, it is taking around 7 seconds and with addition of each search term, time taken for search is linearly increasing. 3GB is the maximum RAM allocated for the solr process. Sample solr search query looks like this

```
tweet_body:*big* AND tweet_body:*data* AND tweet_tag:big_data
```

Any suggestions on improving the speed of searching? Currently I run only 1 shard which contains the entire tweet collection.

Comment: May be with multiple shards with frequently used (probably tweet_tag) as the shard key might help.

Comment: I don't think this is a shard issue, as there is another field over which I do search and that returns really quick. That field is the tweet handle and it returns in like 10 ms.

Comment: Agreed, but when sharding your index size will reduce (as it spreads over multiple shards) and might improve overall performance for you.  Alternatively, your index is running out of memory as well given that you have limited on RAM.  Try increasing the RAM as the entire index can then live in the RAM for faster access.

Comment: Currently, my `Xmx` for the solr process is more than the entire index.

Comment: Did you do an explain on this slow query?  Is that using the index at all?

Comment: @muruga I looked at the explain and it looks like it is returning doc frequency of all the documents for that tag. For example, if the big data tag has 4m documents, then the query explain shows the doc frequency as 4m. Does this mean that it is not using the index? What would be the fix here?

Comment: Of course, it is not using the index then.  Do you have the entire explain plan?  If so, you can post that part of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query `tweet_body:*big*` can be expected to perform poorly.  Trailing wildcards are easy, Leading Wildcards can be readily handled with a ReversedWildcardFilterFactory.  Both, however, will have to scan every document, rather than being able to utilize the index to locate matching documents.  Combining the two approaches would only allow you to search:

```
tweet_body:*big tweet_body:big*
```

Which is not the same thing.  If you really must search for terms with a leading AND trailing wildcard, I would recommend looking into indexing your data as N-grams.

---

I wasn't previously aware of it, but it seems the `lowercase` field type is a Lowercase filtered KeywordAnalyzer.  This is not what you want.  That means the entire field is treated as a single token.  Good for identification numbers and the like, but not for a body of text you wish to perform a full text search on.

So yes, you need to change it.  `text_general` is probably appropriate.  That will index a correctly tokenized field, and you should be able to performt he query you are looking for with:

```
tweet_body:big AND tweet_body:data AND tweet_tag:big_data
```

You will have to reindex, but there is no avoiding that.  There is no good, performant way to perform a full text search on a keyword field.

Comment: I need to search for tweets containing both `big` and `data` anywhere in the field `tweet_body`. The query I specified is returning right results but it is taking too long, any changes I do to the query does not return the expected results. This might be the result of declaring the field as `lowercase`. Not sure if redeclaring the field as `text_en` and reindexing the entire thing is the only option. Currently I figure that the query is scanning all the documents.

Comment: Yes, the query is scanning all the documents (or at least all that of them that match `tweet_tag:big_data`).  I've added to the answer explaining why `lowercase` type is giving you trouble.  Hopefully that gets things moving a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using filter queries,as filter queries runs in parallel